# buildozer android sdk is not installed

Tags: python, android, sdk, kivy, buildozer

**Versions**

Python: 3.10.12
OS: linux
Buildozer:1.5.0

**Description**

It is not possible to do this without root rights, as the command is called --sdk_root.
Calling buildozer with root rights does not work.
Reinstalling buildozer didn't help, clearing the data didn't help either, VPN didn't help either.

**Logs**

```
buildozer android debug

# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Create directory /home/odinson/PycharmProjects/FindImageDescription/.buildozer
# Create directory /home/odinson/PycharmProjects/FindImageDescription/.buildozer/applibs
# Create directory /home/odinson/PycharmProjects/FindImageDescription/.buildozer/android/platform
# Create directory /home/odinson/PycharmProjects/FindImageDescription/.buildozer/android/app
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /home/odinson/PycharmProjects/FindImageDescription/venv/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run ['git', 'clone', '-b', 'master', '--single-branch', 'https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git', 'python-for-android']
# Cwd /home/odinson/PycharmProjects/FindImageDescription/.buildozer/android/platform
Клонирование в «python-for-android»...
# Run ['/home/odinson/PycharmProjects/FindImageDescription/venv/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-q', 'appdirs', 'colorama>=0.3.3', 'jinja2', 'sh>=1.10, <2.0; sys_platform!="win32"', 'build', 'toml', 'packaging']
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /home/odinson/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/odinson/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
# Recommended android's NDK version by p4a is: 25b
# Android NDK found at /home/odinson/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b
# Installing/updating SDK platform tools if necessary
# Run ['/home/odinson/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager', '--sdk_root=/home/odinson/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk', 'platform-tools']
# Cwd /home/odinson/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
Warning: Failed to connect to host: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
Warning: Failed to connect to host: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Warning: Failed to connect to host: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
Warning: Failed to download any source lists!Fetch remote repository...         
Warning: IO exception while downloading manifest                                
Warning: Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely.            
Warning: Failed to find package platform-tools
```

Comment: Your network connection seems to be bad, because `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml` exists and can be downloaded without any problem.

Comment: @Robert I also checked and the connection is good. Reinstalling `buildozer` did not help, the VPN connection did not help either.

Comment: @Robert I suspect that you need root rights. but I don't understand how to do this. After all, when you try to call a command `sudo buildozer android debug` with root rights, it will write that it does not know such a command.